# Хранение даты не в UTC

Tags: mysql, база-данных, timezone

Подскажите, на какие подводные камни можно наткнуться, если хранить дату не в часовом поясе UTC а в каком-либо другом (местном)? Везде, где я читал информацию по этому вопросу рекомендуется хранить в UTC без объяснения причин. Использую MySQL.

Такой "изврат" нужен по нескольким причинам:
 1. Чтобы не переписывать код уже существующего приложения (во многих месах используется NOW()).
 2. Удобнее смотреть дату в БД через тот же PhpMyAdmin в местном часовом поясе.

На сколько я себе представляю, то единственный "косяк", возможно, это двойная конвертация: TimezoneDB -> TimezoneUTС -> TimezoneUser, вместо TimezoneUTС -> TimezoneUser, если бы время хранилось в UTC, хотя, возможно, и получится обойтись одной: TimezoneDB -> TimezoneUser?

Answer (score 0):

Формально отсутствие UTC (хранение в типе DATETIME, а не в TIMESTAMP) может приводить к различным по сравнению с наличием UTC результатам в буквально паре случаев.

Первое - это если появляется узел, "живущий" в другой зоне (и неважно, клиент это будет или скажем слейв-сервер), в том числе и в случае, когда на таком узле разворачивается бэкап. Впрочем, те же проблемы возможны, если на таком узле неверно настроена зона времени - тут наоборот, наличие UTC приведёт к проблемам.

Второе - это проблемы, связанные с переходом на летнее время и обратно, если оно имеется в текущей зоне времени. Особенно когда корректировка выполняется "в минус" - в БД могут появиться "записи из будущего", и сортировка событий по времени (а также результаты расчёта разницы во времени между записями) не будет соответствовать фактической.